# Cordova and Ionic build error for android

Tags: android, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic to develop an app for android, but whenever I build the application I get this error:

```
[Fatal Error] oss-parent-7.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] oss-parent-7.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] lombok-ast-0.2.3.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.1.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:17.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:transform-api:1.5.0
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.5.0 > com.android.tools:common:24.5.0
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.pom
         > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava-parent:17.0.
            > Could not parse POM file:/C:/Users/renan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/46b8a785b60a2767095b8611613b58577e96d4c9/oss-parent-7.pom
               > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.5.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.5.0
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:24.5.0

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.102 secs
      > Could not parse POM file:/C:/Users/renan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/46b8a785b60a2767095b8611613b58577e96d4c9/oss-parent-7.pom
         > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.5.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.5.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.5.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.5.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
         > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.5.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.5.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.pom
         > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.3.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.5.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:24.5.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:24.5.0
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.3/lombok-ast-0.2.3.pom
         > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:1.0.1.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.5.0 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:1.0-rc5 > com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4:4.5 > com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4-runtime:4.5
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/abego/treelayout/org.abego.treelayout.core/1.0.1/org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.1.pom
         > Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

So I created a new application with cordova, just to test the build android:

```
cordova create test com.example.test Test
cd test
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

And i get the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] oss-parent-7.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:17.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:common:24.0.0
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.pom
         > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava-parent:17.0.
            > Could not parse POM file:/C:/Users/renan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/46b8a785b60a2767095b8611613b58577e96d4c9/oss-parent-7.pom
               > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
         > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.pom
         > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:17.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.2
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.pom
         > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava-parent:17.0.
            > Could not parse POM file:/C:/Users/renan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/46b8a785b60a2767095b8611613b58577e96d4c9/oss-parent-7.pom
               > Content is not allowed in prolog.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.909 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried to download again the Android SDK, uninstall the cordova and ionic, update and clean the npm and them install again. But still did'nt solve the error.

```
Android SDK:  24.4.1 (with API 23)
Cordova:      6.2.0
Ionic:        1.7.15
Gradle:       2.13
Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_65 (Oracle Corporation 25.65-b01)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Changed the classpath of gradle
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
to 
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'

The error remains the same, the only thing that has changed is that it downloads gradle 1.0.1.

```
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.0.1/gradle-1.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/1.0.1/builder-1.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/24.0.1/lint-24.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/1.0.1/builder-model-1.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/1.0.1/builder-test-api-1.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/24.0.1/sdklib-24.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/24.0.1/sdk-common-24.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/common/24.0.1/common-24.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/24.0.1/manifest-merger-24.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/24.0.1/ddmlib-24.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/24.0.1/lint-checks-24.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/24.0.1/layoutlib-api-24.0.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/24.0.1/dvlib-24.0.1.pom
[Fatal Error] oss-parent-7.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/24.0.1/lint-api-24.0.1.pom
...
```

Edit 2:

```
C:\Dev\Workspaces\Cordova\teste>cordova build android --verbose
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
Wrote out Android application name to "Teste"
Wrote out Android package name to "com.exemple.teste"
This app does not have launcher icons defined
updated project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
ANDROID_HOME=G:\android-sdk-windows
JAVA_HOME=C:\Dev\App\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
[Fatal Error] oss-parent-7.pom:2:1: O conte·do nÒo Ú permitido no pr¾logo.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:17.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:common:24.0.0
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.pom
         > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava-parent:17.0.
            > Could not parse POM file:/C:/Users/renan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/46b8a785b60a2767095b8611613b58577e96d4c9/oss-parent-7.pom
               > O conte·do nÒo Ú permitido no pr¾logo.
   > Could not resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
         > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.pom
         > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:17.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.2
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.pom
         > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava-parent:17.0.
            > Could not parse POM file:/C:/Users/renan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/46b8a785b60a2767095b8611613b58577e96d4c9/oss-parent-7.pom
               > O conte·do nÒo Ú permitido no pr¾logo.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 29.823 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Dev\Workspaces\Cordova\teste\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: you need to check your guava classpath in the build.gradle file

Comment: Open your android project and check your poroject build path you are missing some project dependencies.

Comment: @Renan Try deleting .gradle/caches folder and try to rebuild.

Comment: @Ganghi Still with the same error

Comment: @Dar I'm not behind any proxy

Comment: @Atula classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'

Comment: upgrade your build:gradle. higher than 1.0.0 and avoid + sign. get a fixed number classpath

Comment: @Atula I changed to 1.0.1 but still gives the same error, it seems like a dead end, perhaps the solution is to format and reinstall the windows

Comment: @RenanWillian I hope I got you in time, but don't reinstall Windows for this just yet. Please try `cordova clean android` before doing so. Then `cordova build android --verbose`. Update to us your log result.

Comment: @Dan thanks for the answer, cordova clean android gives the exact same error that cordova build android, I'll edit the post with the results of cordova build android --verbose